# How to create an exception with redirection to user-friendly error page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, controller, elmah

I have an MVC action which generates a Word document:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExportToWord(string docId)
    {
    try
    {
      //...
      //Word-document generating is done here...
      //...
      return File(stream, MIMEAssistant.GetMIMEType("docx"), fileName + ".docx");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Problem with generating! " + e.ToString());
    }
```

If I have  so I get en Asp.Net standard exception with URL

```
http://localhost:18314/Export/ExportToWord?docId=5
```

If I have  so I have the same URL. Redirection is not done. It must go to

```
http://localhost:18314/Home/ErrorPage.
```

Now users do not get any error page, just reloading of the page. The page is reloaded not correctly because the URL is

```
http://localhost:18314/Export/ExportToWord?docId=5
```

I hope it was understandable description :)

Question: How to make correct redirection to .../Home/ErrorPage and send an exception by using Elmah logging facility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `return RedirectToAction("ErrorPage", "Home");` instead of throwing exception. There are [`RedirectToAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470154%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) overloads which allows to pass route values (so you can pass your error id, exception type etc).

**UPDATE**

As you want to log exceptions using ELMAH, then I suggest logging errors manually and redirecting to action with:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
    return RedirectToAction("ErrorPage", "Home");
}
```

Comment: But I need to get exception by email. I use Elmah http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC for reporting of errors.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think that you should include ELMAH in your original question.

Comment: Nice! I did not know that I can send error message with Elmah like this. Thanks a lot! The question includes Elmah now. :-)